# Typo3 using constants in "Constant" field

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to form file path.
In "Constant" field:

```
const.siteName = site
templates = fileadmin/templates/{$const.siteName}/
```

When i look in typoscript object browser:

```
[siteName] = site    
[templates] = fileadmin/templates/{$const.siteName}/
```

Is it possible to achieve this:

```
[templates] = fileadmin/templates/site/
```

using `const.siteName`?

If yes, how?

=========================================================================

EDIT:

What i am tying to do is next:

In my extension configuration

```
const.siteName = foo
const.templates = fileadmin/templates/($const.siteName)/
const.path.extensions = ($const.templates)/ext/
```

I include my extension in typoscript template. In my extension setup i include setup for plugin like this:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:foo/Configuration/TypoScript/Plugin/formhandler.ts">
```

In Configuration/TypoScript/Plugin/formhandler.ts:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler {
    /* snip */
    settings.predef.member {
        templateFile.value = {$const.path.extensions}formhandler/member/step-1.html // doesn't work
        //templateFile.value = fileadmin/templates/foo/ext/formhandler/member/step-1.html // works
    }
    /* snip */
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, this example works perfect:

**Constants:**

```
const.test = foo
const.test2 = {$const.test}/bar
```

**Setup:**

```
page = PAGE

page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = {$const.test}
page.10.wrap = <p>|</p>

page.20 = TEXT
page.20.value = {$const.test2}
page.20.wrap = <p>|</p>
```

**Output in Browser:**

```
foo

foo/bar
```

Tested with TYPO3 4.5 and 8.3

Comment: However the TypoScript Objectbrowser doesn't resolve constants in the constants section. Nevertheless, the usage in frontend works just fine!

Comment: Your example works but not for me. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @EvilPenguin Don't use `( ) ` but `{ }` for constants you got that wrong in one of your code examples.

Comment: I could add that this (sometimes) works in the frontend due to *multiple TypoScript parsing passes* which among other things happens when there are remaining INCLUDE statements. It might not consistently happen on all sites! And *if* it does not happen, constants-inside-constants would likely never be replaced. The reason is that replacement happens internally with `str_replace` and multiple passes has the first pass replacing to something that contains a second reference; second pass then replaces that reference. Rely on this if you can but use with great care!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the TYPO3 NG/ML/Forum:

https://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&th=212721&goto=740111&#msg_740111
there are a lot of hints how to use constants in typoscript:

you can reuse constants in constants definition, but only up to 10 levels deep.

you can use constants in conditions, but only in setup-part

Comment: This still seems to be correct with TYPO3 11, `[{$myPid} in tree.rootLineIds]` would not work for constants

Answer (score 0):

short : NO

long: you can only use constants in your setup.

what you can do is:

CONSTANTS

```
const.siteName = site
const.templatePath = fileadmin/templates
```

SETUP:

```
myTemplate= {$const.templatePath}/{$const.siteName}
```